# Get tons of email using Designer Workflow

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, outlook

Hi why do I get **TONS** of email using this SP Designer workflow when I change the **trigger** from Don't **send email** to **Sent email**. I just want only 1 email received not more .

Please find 3 attached picture below !

Thanks in advanced

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you share whole Workflow process?

Comment: yeah . i already update the new picture.

Comment: Check the Workflow's Start option as if "Start workflow automatically when an item is changed" is select. And if that is yes, then there is a chance that when ever the excel is oped it is sending the email.

Comment: @Md.TahmidulAbedin so I just tick " when an item is changed only" or tick all of the option?

Answer (score 1):

If the workflow runs on change it will evaluate the step every time - NOT only the first time it was set. This means that every time somebody change the item and `Trigger = Send mail` it will evaluate true and do what you have inside the if statement.

If you only want to send the mail once, you need to make an extra field to keep track of if you have send the mail or not. Then you add an if statement `If Has send mail = false send mail and set field has send mail = true`.

If you want it to send a mail every time the trigger is set (Assuming in the items lifecycle it can go back and forth between sending items or not) you would need a field to keep track of the "old" field value then match against it and only trigger if the old value is different from then new value.

Hope this helps clearing up workflow logic a bit.

Comment: "If Has send mail = false send mail and set field has send mail = true." How can I do this sir? can u help?

Comment: You first need to create a boolean field (preset to No). Then in your workflow click just below the text in the IF statement and add another IF statement and use the boolean field you just created. Finally inside the IF statement add an action 'set field in current item' choose the boolean field and set it to Yes.